# How to use BMP280 SPI Kernel Module

Tags: kernel, spi, device-tree

I got a adafruit BME280 sensor board and I wired it to the raspberry pi zero via spi. According to the datasheet I can read sensor data from the device via the userspace spi interface. Everything works fine from userspace.

I discovered, that there is a [kernel module](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/iio/pressure/bmp280-spi.c) for this sensor available utilizing the iio subsystem. And it implements the algorithms from the datasheet. A naive `modprobe bcmp280_spi` loaded the module:

```
# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
bmp280_spi              3451  0
bmp280                 11976  1 bmp280_spi
industrialio           50711  1 bmp280
spidev                  7034  0
...
```

But there is nothing to interface with:

```
# tree /sys/bus/iio/
/sys/bus/iio/
|-- devices
|-- drivers
|-- drivers_autoprobe
|-- drivers_probe
`-- uevent

2 directories, 3 files
```

Could someone help me with setting up the BMP280 SPI Kernel Module for the raspberry pi zero? I guess I need a device tree overlay, but I can't find any documentation how to interface this sensor module correctly. The raspberry pi includes a [configuration for i2c](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.9.y/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/bmp085_i2c-sensor-overlay.dts) but I want to use spi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching in google for several painful <s>hours</s> days, I found the solution. Here is my device tree overlay:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "brcm,bcm2708";

    fragment@0 {
        target = <&spidev0>;

        __overlay__ {
            status = "disabled";
        };
    };

    fragment@1 {
        target = <&spi0>;

        __overlay__ {
            status = "okay";
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;

            bme280@0 {
                compatible = "bosch,bme280";
                reg = <0x0>;
                spi-max-frequency = <500000>;
                default-oversampling = <1>;
                status = "okay";
            };
        };
    };
};
```

It is important to disable the `spidev` node, since otherwise it conflicts with the chipselect. If you see something like this in `dmesg`, then you have disabled the wrong node:

```
[   85.280101] spi-bcm2835 20204000.spi: chipselect 0 already in use
[   85.280123] spi_master spi0: spi_device register error /soc/spi@7e204000/bme280@0
[   85.280138] of_spi_notify: failed to create for '/soc/spi@7e204000/bme280@0'
[   85.280144] OF: changeset notifier error @/soc/spi@7e204000/bme280@0
```

You can use `@spidev0` for chipselect `0` and `@spidev1` for chipselect `1`. It also also important to disable the `spidev` node (=fragment@0) before enabling the sensor driver (=fragment@1).

An out of tree device tree compiler is needed to compile the overlay. I used [this script](https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki/FBTFT-RPI-overlays) to get one. The device tree overlay can be compiled and applied as follows:

```
# dtc -@ -I dts -O dtb -o /boot/overlays/bmp280-spi.dtbo bmp280-spi.dts
# dtoverlay /boot/overlays/bmp280-spi.dtbo
```

After the device tree overlay has been applied, sensor is there:

```
# cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_temp_input 
26980
```

To apply the overlay at bootup, add this line to `/boot/config.txt`

```
dtoverlay=bmp280-spi
```